# "unsupported operand type(s) for %" when building SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am using `PASSWORD` in SQL to hash user passwords.

```
sql = text('insert into account values("%s", "%s", "%s", PASSWORD("%s"), "1" )'%(fname, lname, user_name, password))
```

When I try to log in using the password it wont allow me to access the account.

```
sql = text('select * from account where account.user_name = "%s"  and account.password = PASSWORD("%s") and account.active = ' + '"' + '1' + '"')%(user_name, password)
```

I get the error:

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'TextClause' and 'tuple'
```

What am I doing wrong when trying to access the encrypted password?

Answer (score 11):

The *immediate error* is that in the first example you used string formatting `%` on the string, and then enclosed the result in `text`, while the second one tries to use string formatting on the `text` object.

The **more severe problem** is that you've opened yourself to injection attacks by formatting user input directly into the SQL string rather than passing them separately.

It looks like you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy.  In that case, write a parameterized query and pass the parameters to be properly escaped to `execute`.

```
db.engine.execute(
    'insert into account values(?, ?, ?, PASSWORD(?), ?)',
    (fname, lname, user_name, password, True)
)

db.engine.execute(
    'select * from account where account.user_name = ?  and account.password = PASSWORD(?) and account.active = ?,
    (user_name, password, True)
)
```

The parameterized concept is similar for any other database driver.

---

Rather than relying on the database to hash the passwords, using the [`passlib`](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/new_app_quickstart.html) library is a much more robust alternative.  It contains much stronger hashes, as well as the ability to "deprecate" hashes and upgrade the stored value.

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha512

# when creating a user, generate the hash with passlib
# and don't use PASSWORD() in SQL
password = pbkdf2_sha512.encrypt('secret')

# example login
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        r = engine.execute('select * from account where account.name = ? and account.active = ?', (username, True))

        if r:
            user = r[0]

            # verify the hash using passlib, not SQL
            if pbkdf2_sha512.verify(password, user.password):
                # active user, correct password, do the login
                return 'good credentials'

        # incorrect username or password
        return 'bad credentials'

    return render_template('login.html')
```

Pass these hashes in, rather than calling `PASSWORD` in SQL.